# mod rewrite back reference not working

Tags: php, regex, mod-rewrite, apache2

I am working on rewrite but it is not working for me. I already wasted my 2 days for it. Your help will be appreciatable.

```
RewriteRule test/(.*)/(.*)/$ /include/test?$1=$2   //not working
RewriteRule test/(\w+)/(\w+)/$ /include/test?$1=$2   //not working
RewriteRule ^test/(\w+)/(\w+)/$ /include/test?$1=$2  //not working

RewriteRule .* include/test.php?id=123     //working
```

**Trying PHP code**

```
echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']   // include/test.php/id/1234 (after rewrite)
                            // expecting :  /include/test.php?id=1234
```

**Request by user url :**

```
 http://www.example.com/include/test/id/1234
```

**Rewite to:**

```
http://www.example.com/include/test.php?id=1234
```

**Possible issues:**

- not fetch values of $1, $2
- not matching pattern (although patterns are current)
- not redirecting to substitutes(internally)

**Main problem:**

Not getting `$_GET` value

**Test.php**

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors",1);
echo $_GET['id'];
echo  $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'<br/>';
echo $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];
?>
```

On requesting

```
http://www.example.com//include/test/id/1234
```

Output:

```
/include/test.php/id/1234
/id/1234
```

Comment: Do you mean that you are not getting other query string parameters?

Comment: Getting include/test.php/id/1234 instead of include/test.php?id=1234, Not getting $1 & $2 i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules look okay, the only problem I can see is the trailing slash for your test URI: http://www.example.com/include/test/id/1234

Please try:

```
RewriteRule test/(.*)/(.*)/?$ /include/test.php?$1=$2
RewriteRule test/(\w+)/(\w+)/?$ /include/test.php?$1=$2
RewriteRule ^test/(\w+)/(\w+)/?$ /include/test.php?$1=$2
```

Also you do not need all three of the rules above.  The first one should cover both first and second.  So, you can remove the second one.  I just kept it there assuming these are your different tests.

**Update:**

Adds `.php` extension to destination URI, i.e. replaces `/include/test?$1=$2` with `/include/test.php?$1=$2`

Comment: same problem, Not getting $_GET value on requested file

Comment: @BOSS, copy paste error. Updated answer to use `test.php` instead of just `test`.  Please give it a try again.

Comment: @BOSS, I can't seem to reproduce this.  I am getting `$_GET` values fine.  Just to make sure, your `test.php` is in `/include/` directory correct?

Comment: Oh an by the way in the working rewrite rule that you have posted in your question add a leading slash and try it: `RewriteRule .* /include/test.php?id=123`

Comment: rewrite seems currect. Is there anything external that affacts rewrite

Comment: If that one rewrite works, others should too as far as external influence is concerned.  The only thing I can think of is the regex which is working fine for me.  You could try escaping those slashes i.e. replace `/` with `\/`, which I don't think will change the result but just for test purpose.